# Find commands of default keyboard typing shortcuts in Gnome 3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

I have Debian GNU/Linux 8 Jessie (DE GNOME Shell 3.14.2) installed on my machine.
After having set <kbd>Alt + PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Alt + PageDown</kbd> shortcuts for multimedia sound volume Up\Down respectively, I found my default Up\Down-volume shortcuts <kbd>Fn + F2</kbd> and <kbd>Fn + F3</kbd> not working.
Worth to mention that sound On\Off <kbd>Fn + F1</kbd> works well.

I'm going to add *"duplicate"* shortcuts <kbd>Fn + F2/F3</kbd> which will Up-and-Down volume as <kbd>Alt + PageUp/PageDown</kbd> now do. But I couldn't find the `Command` for any these default shortcuts (all i can do is to change shortcut combination; can't change even its `Name` field!).

And here is the question: where can I find the commands of these default keyboard shortcuts?

*(I'll attach a few screenshots, maybe they will clarify this issue)* 
*This is what I call the "default" shortcut, whose `Command` I want to find:*
[image: This is what I call the "default" shortcut, whose <code>Command</code> I want to find.]

*And here are Name and Command fields I'm talking about.*
[image: This is Name and Command fields I'm talking about.]

---

**SOLUTION:**

Finally, with a hint of *[don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142)* user, I created two scripts and passed as `Command` their location in this way:

Location, also a `Command`:

```
/usr/MY_SCRIPTS/volumeUp.sh
```

Script itself:

```
amixer -q sset Master 3%+
```

***Now, it works!*** The notification pop-up icon that shows the level appears only with default <kbd>Fn + F2(F3)</kbd> but it doesn't matter (maybe, I'll try to solve this later).

***However***, the there is still no answer on question where to find the commands like: sound  volume up/down, turn ON/OFF the display, enable Numpad, display brightness More/Less, turn On/Off wireless etc., you know, all these actions which are marked on laptops' keyboard.

So I'll keep this question open until it becomes clear.

*(**UPDATE:** will edit Q and post A soon.)*

Comment: Shortcuts are controlled by the desktop environment, not by the distribution. What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @don_crissti, thanks for attention! Now, when I have set Volume Up\Down to Fn+F2(F3), and according to a link you gave, `amixer -q sset Master 3%+` to Alt+PageUp(Down), the Fn-combinations work well now, but pressing Alt+PadeUp(Down) causes setting Volume level to `0`.  Here I can guess it sees another combiation, but there's something wrong with something... I, I don't know.
I remember how on Windows I had default (Fn+F2(F3)) working well, and set up additional Alt+PageUp(Down) in AIMP3 audio player. But there is no such key-binding option in Rhythmbox, that's a pity!

Comment: @Gilles, GNOME Shell 3.14.2

Comment: @don_crissti, standard (that's Fn-combinations) are because there is marked keys on the keyboard, so other people will be able to change the volume level. Alt-combinations are for specially me ;) It's on my laptop (Dell Latitude 3340), as all keys are in one area, I use them to control multimedia: Alt+PageUp(Down) for volume, Alt+Left(Right) for prev or next track, Alt+Down for play\pause, Alt+Up for stop.
And it would be better to make Alt-s for +/- 3%, while Fn-s will change it by 6%.

Comment: Works fine here both with `pactl` and `amixer` though  I placed the commands in two separate scripts and the two shortcuts run the scripts.

Comment: @don_crissti, it works now! See added solution info. Thank you for a hint about scripts -- I did so and it helped.

Comment: I guess a more appropriate question title would be _"How are hotkeys (Fn + F) handled in Gnome 3 ?"_ . The answer is _"via gnome-settings-daemon"_. Check the [source code](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/master/plugins/media-keys/README.media-keys-API) and the [plugins](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/master/plugins). Though this will be really broad so you should try to narrow it... what exactly are you trying to accomplish ? You can always have two sets of shortcuts and switch them via dconf/gsettings if you want...